# How should I set the url prefix for the onlyoffice server ？

Tags: node.js, onlyoffice

```
 Now I integrate the onlyoffice service into the web front-end pages.I need to redirect the onlyoffce edit page to the url prefixed。 
 example ： 
     onlyoffice inside redirect url  :  
       http://domain:port/6.4.0-121/web-apps/apps/presentationeditor/main/index_loader.html
     prefixed onlyoffice inside redirect ulr : 
       http://domain:port/custonPrefix/6.4.0-121/web-apps/apps/presentationeditor/main/index_loader.html
```

Does anyone know where I can configure the onlyoffce server custom prefix ？

I tried adding editorConfig Param customUrlPrefix to the DocsAPi class, but it did't worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual paths for the Document Server can only be set using proxy.
You can configure Nginx installed with the Document Server on the same server as proxy the following way

Install Document Server on a custom port using the official installation guide.

Run Nginx as proxy on ports 80/443 using [this article](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-proxy/tree/master/nginx#readme%204)

Use [the following configuration](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-proxy/blob/master/nginx/proxy-to-virtual-path.conf) file for Nginx

Link to general information: [Using ONLYOFFICE Docs behind the proxy](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/docs-community-proxy.aspx)